# SQL Search a value like

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhxcV.png)

I already tried as shown below, but it fails to search

```
DECLARE @INVOICE_NO nvarchar(100) = 4090

SELECT 
    ORDER_NO, CUST_NAME, MODEL_NO, SERVICE_DATE, INVOICVE_NO 
FROM 
    Table_Name 
WHERE 
    @INVOICE_NO LIKE LTRIM(RTRIM(INVOICE_NO))
```

Comment: Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c77c02ed39ae05e0a1f6a4d00f83811f)

Comment: I see all your questions have been down-voted. Maybe it's time you took the [tour] and learned [ask]. (You get a bronze badge for doing so :-)

Answer (score 0):

concatenation usually works :)

```
declare @INVOICE_NO nvarchar(100)=4090

SELECT ORDER_NO,CUST_NAME,MODEL_NO,SERVICE_DATE,INVOICVE_NO FROM Table_Name 
WHERE @INVOICE_NO like '%'+LTRIM(RTRIM(INVOICE_NO))+'%'
```

Comment: Are you sure your SQL produces the correct result? (Apart from the typo: `INVOICVE_NO`)

Comment: only can find the result , INVOICE_NO=4 only